# Javascript proxies were not generated for the controller: cannot use public remoted methods in Iframe?

Tags: apex, javascript

I am trying to navigate between a page to another where it uses JsRemoting.
When i run the second page alone it works fine. But when i go from first page to another
it throws me this kind of error.

Please help me .
What does the Javascript proxies mean?[image]

Comment: try changing the access modifier of the remoting methods to global

Comment: This is covered in the documentation for the [@RemoteAction annotation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm).

Comment: Doc specific to [Scope and Visibility of @RemoteAction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_scope_visibility.htm):

Answer (score 22):

The controller and remote action functions have to be global

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: +1 on Metadday's comment, your on the correct path with this answer, the community, future readers and thus your reputation points will all benefit from some links and quotations from the help topics that support your answer.

Answer (score 3):

As per salesforce documentation about scope and visibility of RemoteActions if public RemoteAction methods cannot be used in iframe which is mentioned in error message also.

Following is link of latest documentation on this subject:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_scope_visibility.htm

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have solution for this already but incase you have downloaded an App from the AppExchange, Pardot App to be more specific and you have access to Salesforce engage as well, this is a result of adding fields in the Leads and Contacts Page Layout, so if you remove Marketing Action Summary Contact, Pardot Mobile List Membership, Pardot Mobile Activities, Pardot Mobile Social Data and Add to Pardot List you should be good. Just keep the mandatory fields namely: Pardot Activities, Pardot List Membership and Pardot Social.It worked for me.

Regards,
Osama Ahmad