# Visualforce Remoting: Javascript proxies were not generated for controller QuoteLayout: may not use public remoted methods inside an iframe

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, controller, remote-action

I've looked at all of these solutions here on SFDC stack exchange ([1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145577/visualforce-remoting-javascript-proxies-were-not-generated-for-controller-xyz)) ([2](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000092ZfIAI)) ([3](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17323/javascript-proxies-were-not-generated-for-the-controller-cannot-use-public-remo)). I followed them for what applied to what I'm doing and I'm still getting this error.

I made my apex class global instead of public. I changed the method to global instead of public.

```
global with sharing class QuoteLayout
```

And the method looks like this.

```
    @remoteAction
    global static void syncIt(String quoteId){
    System.debug('QuoteLayout : syncIt');
    Try{
        Quote quoteObj = [SELECT OpportunityId, IsSyncing, Service_Template_Codes__c FROM Quote WHERE Id = :quoteId];
        Opportunity oppObj = [SELECT Id, SyncedQuoteId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :quoteObj.OpportunityId];
        Contract_Document__c cd = [SELECT Implementation__c FROM Contract_Document__c WHERE Opportunity__c = :oppObj.Id];
        cd.Implementation__c = quoteObj.Service_Template_Codes__c;
        oppObj.SyncedQuoteId = quoteObj.Id;
        System.debug('SyncedQuoteId = ' + oppObj.SyncedQuoteId);
        update cd;
        update oppObj;
    }
    Catch(exception e){
        system.debug(logginglevel.error, '*****'+e);
    }
}
```

And here is my visualforce page.

```
<apex:page id="pg" standardController="Quote" extensions="QuoteLayout">
<apex:remoteObjects >
    <apex:remoteObjectModel name="Quote" jsShorthand="q" 
                            fields="Id,License_Start_Date__c,License_Term_in_months__c,License_End_Date__c">
    </apex:remoteObjectModel>
</apex:remoteObjects>
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock id="pb"> 
        <apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <button id="startSyncButton" style="{!if(syncStatus == 'This','display: none;','')}" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" type="button" onclick="syncIt();">Start Sync</button>
            <button id="stopSyncButton" style="{!if(syncStatus == 'This','display: inline;','display: none;')}" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" type="button" onclick="stopSync();">Stop Sync</button>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>    

<script type="text/javascript">
var syncStatus = "{!syncStatus}";

function syncIt() {
    console.log('syncIt');
    var quoteId,
        spinOriginalClass;
    quoteId = "{!quoteObj.Id}";
    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.QuoteLayout.syncIt}', quoteId, function (result, event) {
        if (event.status) {
            document.getElementById("startSyncButton").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("stopSyncButton").style.display = "inline";
            syncStatus = "This";
        } else {
            alert("Something went wrong please try again.");
        }
    })
}

function stopSync() {
    console.log('stopSync');
    // console.log('>>>quoteObj.Id', quoteObj.Id);
    var quoteId = "{!quoteObj.Id}";
    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.QuoteLayout.stopSync}', quoteId, function (result, event) {
        if (event.status) {
            document.getElementById("startSyncButton").style.display = "inline";
            document.getElementById("stopSyncButton").style.display = "none";
            syncStatus = "None";
        } else {
            alert("Something went wrong please try again.");
        }
    })
}

function syncDone() {
    console.log('syncDone');
    document.getElementById("syncDone").style.display = "none";
}

</script>
```

This is what the errors look like as well when the page loads. The alert appears 1st and then I see the same message appear in the console. Any idea or clue to what is happening here?

[image]
[image]

Comment: did you ever solve this?